# Rails include page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How would I include a page from the public folder in one of my views? I want to include a single header like I do in PHP so when I make a change it affects all the other pages. (It is for multiple views)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the most part, the only web pages in the public folder will be purely static (custom 404 pages, FAQ, etc).  If you have a piece of static HTML that you'd like to be displayed in a lot of pages, a [partial](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Partials.html) is what you're looking for.

A partial doesn't **have** to be tied to a controller.  You can create the sub-directory:

```
/views/static
```

and fill it with a whole bunch of partials, so you would have:

```
/views/static/_my_first_partial.html.erb
/views/static/_my_second_partial.html.erb
```

and anywhere you want those fragments, you can do:

```
render :partial => "static/my_first_partial"
```

and voila, you're done!

Comment: Thank you, you have saved me a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty new to rails, but I guess for such task you would use Layouts:
[Layouts and Rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

Comment: Yes you're on the right track there, I think he's after a partial, in which case he'll need to move the page out of the public folder.